# Importing data in a data extension and avoiding errors

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, error-messages, import, database.insert

When we define a data extension in Marketing Cloud with two fields:

- Email (254)
- Company (50)

If we try to import records with "Company" values that includes length of 50 or under and some values with greater than 50 characters.

Only those rows are inserted that includes "Company" value less than or equal to 50 character limit. Rest with greater than 50 characters value errors out.
*`exceeded the max field length of`*

**Question** - Is it possible to avoid the error so value up to 50 characters is inserted and extra characters are truncated?

Comment: No, your use case would be to import the complete data then use SQL query to return a substring() to a new DE

Comment: Hi @EazyE Using a query and pushing the data in a new DE would be data manipulation. But, it can only use  the records that are present in the original data extension. My question is focused on the original data extension. How to make sure importing data to the original DE is successful at the first place so I am not losing any records during the import due to the character length issue. Is it possible that data extension accept defined length of character and if imported data includes more than defined length, then values are simple truncated. This way at least record makes it to the DE

Comment: answer is still No, you should know the max length of the field in your file and mimic that in your DE setup

Comment: Ok - so, if I understood this correctly, there is no way data can be imported in a truncated manner. It will be either pass (inserted) or fail completely?

Comment: Why would you want to truncate the company name? Isn't the obvious solution to just increase the character limit of the field in the data extension?

Comment: Hi Antonio, I understand that solution is to increase the character limit. But, I'm simply asking a generic question (not limited to a company name field) where if data is being pushed to a DE in an automated fashion (millions of records) without knowing the source values, if DE is able to accept the records (even with the truncation). Instead of erroring out.

Comment: The answer, as @EazyE has stated now twice, is still no. This is not possible. If a field in a file is outside the specs set in the receiving DE, then it will fail.

Comment: Thank you @Gortonington for the confirmation.